# Sign Up form Fatal error: Call to undefined function _content_is_empty()

Tags: entities, nodes, users

i have a sign up form that was working correctly until recently i just used it for a test signup and it throws this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function _content_is_empty() 
in sites/all/modules/cck/content.module on line 920

And when i look into line 920 it has this code

```
915     // Filter out items flagged for removal.
916      $filtered = array();
917      $function = $field['module'] .'_content_is_empty';
918      foreach ((array) $items as $delta => $item) {
919        if (empty($item['_remove'])) {
920          $filtered[] = ($function($item, $field) ? $empty : $item);
921        }
922      }
```

Any one has any idea. I wonder if its due to the Display fields change in a Custom Data type.?

Comment: this might not be a problem caused by the content module. Clear the caches and see if it works; then try disabling the contributed modules one by one and see if it works again. You might find the culprit module which caused this error.

Comment: Solved by applying this Patch http://drupal.org/files/issues/cck_node_validate_1.patch

Comment: good :) you should report that the patch does work on drupal.org

Comment: what is your drupal version exactlly?

Comment: I think usulally patching is not good solution.your problem maybe in another place (but this patch in not  destruction patch).

Comment: Drupal Version 6.25